# lme4 upgrade produces error message Error in `[[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, i, value = integer(0))

Tags: r, lme4

I have constructed a generalized mixed linear model with lmer (lme4) last week which worked fine:

```
fit<-lmer(dat$presence~log(dat$SIZE_strict)*dat$Troph_level+log(dat$HAB500EXCL_strict+1)+(1|dat$dataset), family=poisson, REML=FALSE)
```

After updating the lme4 package however, the model no longer worked, giving the error message:

```
Error in `[[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, i, value = integer(0)) : 
  replacement has 0 rows, data has 174
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In lmer(dat$presence ~ log(dat$SIZE_strict) * dat$Troph_level +  :
  calling lmer with 'family' is deprecated; please use glmer() instead
2: In checkArgs("glmer", REML = FALSE) :
  extra argument(s) ‘REML’ disregarded
```

Using glmer instead of lmer did not solve the first error message. Any suggestions would be very much appreciated!

Here are some of the data (called dat):

```
Troph_level presence    dataset SIZE_strict HAB500EXCL_strict
carnivorous 2   1   46155   26005
carnivorous larvae  0   1   46155   26005
phytophagous    2   1   46155   26005
phytophagous    0   3   195295  360882
carnivorous 0   3   195295  360882
carnivorous larvae  0   3   195295  360882
phytophagous    4   2   18272   21169
carnivorous larvae  0   2   18272   21169
carnivorous 1   2   18272   21169
carnivorous 1   2   24964   26745
carnivorous larvae  0   2   24964   26745
phytophagous    4   2   24964   26745
phytophagous    5   2   6220    12543
carnivorous larvae  0   2   6220    12543
carnivorous 1   2   6220    12543
phytophagous    0   3   102633  12198
carnivorous larvae  0   3   102633  12198
carnivorous 0   3   102633  12198
phytophagous    0   3   2092    291439
carnivorous larvae  1   3   2092    291439
carnivorous 0   3   2092    291439
phytophagous    3   5   80410   0
```

Many thanks in advance!
Toos van Noordwijk

Answer (score 1):

This is a buglet in the new version of `lme4` (to be fixed in an upcoming patch release) that requires grouping variables to be findable within the data frame specified by the `data` argument.  In general things will work more smoothly (and your code will be easier to read) if you use the `data` argument and eschew using variables of the form `dat$var`, for example:

```
fit <- glmer(presence~log(SIZE_strict)*Troph_level+log(HAB500EXCL_strict+1)+
  (1|dataset), family=poisson, data=dat)
```

Comment: the patch release (1.0-5) should be out now.