# R lmer debugging: Error in [[<-.data.frame(*tmp*, i, value = integer(0)) : replacement has 0 rows, data has 117

Tags: r, lme4, lmer

I am able to use `lmer` on an older computer without this error, but the new version (downloaded yesterday) gives me this error message:

```
Error in [[<-.data.frame(*tmp*, i, value = integer(0)) : replacement has 0 rows, data has 117
```

in response to this function:

```
model1<-lmer(threatened~as.numeric(focal.chel)+as.numeric(opponent.chel)+(1|as.factor(males)),na.action=na.omit,data=spiders)
```

I would really like to be able to use the newer version, as I've read that it has less problems with false convergence than older versions. Any help anyone can offer as to how to get this to run without the above error would be greatly appreciated.

My data can be found here: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/16881915/Rfile.txt

Comment: Looking at the News page for the package - there's reference to a bug on index variables `+(1|as.factor(males))` so it could is likely that the behaviour has changed for this section of your code.  How you go about resolving it, I'm not sure and hopefully someone else will be able to answer.  Knowing the problem area may help in the interim though. http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lme4/news.html

Comment: by the way, when asking questions of this sort it's extremely useful to specify the versions you're using (`sessionInfo()` or `packageVersion("lme4")`) on both computers

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19749313/lme4-upgrade-produces-error-message-even-after-grouping-variables-within-the-dat/20353535#20353535

Comment: and cross-posted discussion at r-help: http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.r.general/303372